# How do I make this black quote background transparent ? and the Wow your audience writing bigger?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to make the quote box transparent and larger the text size.

Original code below.

```
 <div class="quote"><h1>WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br></h1><hr style="margin: 0 20%;">
```

Comment: original code here <div class="quote"><h1>
      WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br>
      </h1><hr style="margin: 0 20%;">

Comment: Do you have a style file somewhere? It will have a `.css` extension. You should look in there for a line that says `.quote {` or similar. That block defines the styles for your quotes

Comment: If you are trying to create transparent text with a colored outline/border, SVG is your answer. The next closest thing is using CSS with a defined text color the same as the page background with a text shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned how much transparency and font size you need so I have taken it randomly. Also you were missing a closing `div` tag.
Here is the code:

```html
<div class="quote" style="opacity:0.5"><h1 style="font-size:50px">WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br></h1></div><hr style="margin: 0 20%;">
```

You have asked to make the complete quote box transparent and not only its background-color(which is white!!). Hopefully this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this without affecting the transparency of the text while making the `background-color` of the `div` that surrounds it transparent, use `rgba` colors instead of `opacity`

The first 3 values are the Red, Green Blue levels, and the 4th number is the transparency on a scale of 0-1.

Learn more about rgba in css [here](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

To increase the size of any font, you can use `font-size`. I used `em` in this example since it is relative to the screen size but you can use any of the [CSS measurement units](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).

```css
.quote {
  background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
  z-index: 22;
}

h1 { font-size: 6em; }

.example {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 10px;
  left: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote"><h1>WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br></h1><hr style="margin: 0 20%;"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

To apply transparency to all elements in a div or to an element itself, you can simply use the `opacity` style from a range of 0-1 like so: `opacity: 0.7;`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had tried both it doesn't seems working. Is there a commend to run after change CSS? Here is my code

Comment: .quote {
 // border:solid 5px white;
 color:#444444;
padding:10px;
  width: 75%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color:white;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
height:auto;
  h1 { font-size: 8em
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

Comment: Also on html 

div class="quote" style+"opacity:0.1"><h1 style+"font-size:50px">
      WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br>
      </h1><hr style="margin: 0 20%;">

Currently no change either way I do the code. 

Many thanks

Comment: @KCChen You'll need to remove the `//` from the `.quote` CSS class. Make sure to put all your CSS styles in the `{ }` and close a specific style with `;` If this doesn't work, make sure there is a space between `:` and the value. (`color: red;`) If you're having trouble, simply look at my code and follow suit with formatting.

Comment: Hi Guys     this worked    div class="quote" style="opacity:0.1"><h1 style="font-size:50px"> WOW YOUR AUDIENCE<br> </h1><hr style="margin: 0 20%;">

Comment: Now I want to make the quote blockbox smaller Just not that wide. How I resize it ? Thanks

Comment: @KCChen If you want to make the box smaller, change the `height` and `width` of the `.example` class I provided. If you want to change the text size, all you need to do is change the `font-size` of the element holding your text to something smaller. You can use something other than `em` such as `px`. I only used `em` since it is proportion based and will keep things looking uniform.